# Datagridview Exceptions

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with one image column.
I am filtering datagridview using textbox with textChanged event.
After every key typed in textbox, i am calling function to update images that read
values from sqlite database and based on condition updates images on filtered rows in datagridview.

**Exceptions :**

> Row provided does not belong to this DataGridView control. Parameter
> name: e.Row
>
> 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
> of the collection.

**The above two exceptions often raised randomly at the same line of code, shown below**

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridViewAllMusicDark.Rows)
```

I have done it using thread

```
                var LockedMusic = db.GetAllLockedMusic();
                Thread thread = new Thread(t =>
                {
                    foreach (var lm in LockedMusic)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridViewAllMusicDark.Rows)
                        {
                            if (lm.Key.Equals(row.Cells[2].Value?.ToString()))
                            {
                                ((DataGridViewImageCell)row.Cells[1]).Description = "locked";
                                ((DataGridViewImageCell)row.Cells[1]).Value = Properties.Resources.Dark_Red_PLPS;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                })
                { IsBackground = true };
                thread.Start();
```

and Asynchronously to avoid performance issue while filtering datagridview

```
                var LockedMusic = db.GetAllLockedMusic();
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
                    foreach (var lm in LockedMusic)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridViewAllMusicDark.Rows)
                        {
                            if (lm.Key.Equals(row.Cells[2].Value?.ToString()))
                            {
                                ((DataGridViewImageCell)row.Cells[1]).Description = "locked";
                                ((DataGridViewImageCell)row.Cells[1]).Value = Properties.Resources.Dark_Red_PLPS;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I am struggling to find the cause of this exception and also solution to fix this, if anyone could help me with it

Comment: What are you doing to make sure that two threads don't try to access the control at the same time? Remember that changes to the UI mist be done on the main thread so that can also cause problems

Comment: If i don't use async or  multi threading. the filtering gridview gets too slow. and i need to filter more than 20k rows

Comment: I'm not saying don't use async or threads, I'm saying that you can't manipulate the UI outside of the main application thread. Do all your background stuff on threads and async, but then you have to marshal back over to the ui dispatcher to update the ui.

Comment: @JohnV How "but then you have to marshal back over to the ui dispatcher to update the ui" How can i do it?

Comment: Depends on winforms or xaml but in winforms every control had a beginibvoke method. In xaml user the dispatcher and do dispatcher.begin invoke

Comment: @JohnV Thank you. beginibvoke works. Now there is no exception but, the search gets slowed same as it works without async and multi threading .

` this.DataGridViewAllMusicDark.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {

                }));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint that thinge are not right is that you have set CheckForIllegalCrosstThreadCalls to false. You should never need to do this.

You have to carefully chose when you will Begin Invoke over the main thread when the changes to your UI. Much of the work does not need to happen on the UI thread (reading a database, doing calculations, etc), so when the user clicks a button, start a task to do all the things that don't affect the UI. Then, when those things are done, take the information you calculated and BeginInvoke it over. It is tricky to keep a UI responsive when there's a lot of data processing in the background. You will have to experiment with the right place to touch the UI. You may need to store up results somehow so that you can update the UI in batches.

In general through, the sequence is:

1. Something happens on the UI thread
2. Start a task or call some async method to do the processing on a different thread.
   -this allows the UI to keep running-
3. When the work is complete, take the new information and Invoke back over to the main thread with your UI updates.

In your case, you can iterate through the data and build a list of all the fields that you need to update and what they should be updated to. Then on the UI thread, iterate through that list to apply the changes to the UI.